# How to Make a table field return as a link (from a simple echo command)

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, echo

I've been trying for hours to figure out how to put a link into the following text output via PHP `echo()`.  I basically want to make the title field I'm pulling from my events table (as seen in #4 in the code below) to come back into the browser as a link instead of just text...

the original code that brings back the event title:

```
<?php
// 3. Perform database Query to bring list of events
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events", $connection);
if (!$result) {
    die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
}

// 4. Use returned Data
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row ["eventtitle"]."<br/>".$row["eventdesc"]."<br/>";
}
?>
```

How would I go about getting that `$row["eventtitle"]` to appear in the browser as a link? Let's say if the link was just "eventprofile.php".  This is probably an easy fix, but I've been getting a million errors with trying different things with `<a href>`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events", $connection);
if (!$result) {
 die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo "<a href=\"eventprofile.php\">".$row["eventtitle"]."</a><br/>".$row["eventdesc"]."<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You have double double quotes in that echo statement. That's gonna error out.

Comment: yeah didn't check it, sorry & fixed

Answer (score 0):

add an anchor tag for it!!

```
echo "<a href=\"" . $row['eventtitle'] . "\">" . $row['eventtitle'] . '</a>' . "<br />" .$row["eventdesc"]."<br/>";
```

And thats it.